# Unknown API key '12345678910' in Cloudinary , but the unknown key is the same as my Cloudinary API Key: 12345678910

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudinary

I have a program that uploads images to Cloudinary.  When I run it on my program (localhost) + Heroku, it worked fine(in the past). But now it's not working.

the error is :

***Unknown API key "12345678910"***

The most confusing part to me is that when the error message prints out "Unknown API Key: 12345678910" the unknown key is the same as my Cloudinary API Key: 12345678910.

Please help me . **Thank you in advance**.

[image]

**My .env file**

```
CLOUDINARY_NAME = 'dupz*****' 
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY = '532746917******' 
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET = 'WpTLLxyJZlMwjUITP**********'
```

**Here is my server.js file**

```js
const app = require("./app");
const { connectDatabase } = require("./config/database");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
connectDatabase();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});
```

**Here is my Post.js file**

```js
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const User = require("../models/User");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary");
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.image, {
      folder: "posts",
    });
    const newPostData = {
      caption: req.body.caption,
      image: {
        public_id: myCloud.public_id,
        url: myCloud.secure_url,
      },
      owner: req.user._id,
    };

    const post = await Post.create(newPostData);

    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    user.posts.unshift(post._id);

    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Post created",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message you receive from Cloudinary in your screenshot, it shows the unknown API key that was sent in your upload request - notice the API Key is within single quotes in the error message. The single quotes should not be part of the value sent in your request.

You should be able to resolve it by removing the single quotes from around the values in your `.env` file and retrying the request again.

Comment: Thanks, man! now it's working ! I removed single quotes from CLOUDINARY_API_KEY  then it shows the same problem but this time with CLOUDINARY_NAME, so I removed single quotes from there too, and boom! It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like your code is correct, if it used to run fine, then the code is likely not the problem but Cloudinary itself.

Likely problems

1. You've reached the limits of your account and ignored their emails, they have deactivated your account. [Described in this article](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202521702-What-happens-if-I-exceed-the-usage-limits-of-my-account-s-plan-)
2. Wrong Key

Comment: Thank you for your reply . 1.  My "Credit Usage For Last 30 Days 0.17 of 25....means
0.68% used" 
2. The key I used is the same as my Cloudinary API Key. Now what? Please help me.

Comment: @AkashDas I added some details in a separate answer - please try the steps from that.